# list of list comparison with respect to a integer value in tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda, tuples

I am trying to create a function which takes 2 list of lists and a integer as input:

```
list1 = [[2, 47, -42], [-42, 29, -45], [24, -11, 18], [-34, -4, -14], [-42, -45, 49], [-21, -6, 12]]
list2 = [[13, 15, -11], [35, -5, -42], [-42, 29, -45], [-48, 8, 26], [-42, 29, -45]]
integer = -42
```

And first, check tuples in list1 with -42 as variable and then check the count of same tuples in list2 which are in list1 with -42.
For above example, output should be: 2 as

```
In list1(tuple with -42): [[2, 47, -42],[-42, 29, -45],[-42, -45, 49]]
list2(similar tuples):[[-42, 29, -45],[-42, 29, -45]]
count: 2
```

What I tried until now:

```
res = sum(x == y for x, y in zip(list1,list2))
```

upper code isn't giving any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def abs_double_list(l):
    return [[abs(y) for y in x] for x in l]

res = sum( x in abs_double_list(list1) and abs(integer) in x for x in abs_double_list(list2))
```

That solves your problem. The problem is that you don't compare each element of the list with each other because zip makes pair of element in the list so you only compare the pair with each other (elements on index 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on but never with other indexes)

@Edit independent of negative values

Comment: Is there any method to handle negative value, like making all variable in list1 and list2 positive?

Comment: @User only for the comparison or do you want to create new lists?

Comment: while doing this conversion only

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is a guard and then use the second condition to do the `sum()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
sum(sum(x == y for y in list2) for x in list1 if integer in x)

Out[]:
2
```

But you could do this differently (more efficiently) if these were truly tuples using `collections.Counter()`:

```
In []:
c = Counter(tuple(y) for y in list2)
sum(c[tuple(x)] for x in list1 if integer in x)

Out[]:
2
```